# Dictionary of Dataframes from existing Data frames

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, dataframe

I have the following code for creating a dictionary of data frames using csv files:

```
l = ['employees','positions']
d = {}
for x in l:
    d[x] = pd.read_csv("P:\\python_work\\data_sets\\" + x + ".csv")
```

How would I do the same using a list of data frames that already exist in memory?

This doesn't work but maybe it helps clarify what I'm trying to do:

```
l = ['df1','df2']
d = {}
for x in l:
    d[x] = x
```

I would then be able to access individual data frames like so:

```
d['df1']
```

I provided the example using csv files because it works and it has the same end result (a dictionary of data frames).

Here's an example of the desired contents of the dictionary:

```
{'employees':    id   name      date
 0   1    bob  1/1/2018
 1   2  sally  1/2/2018, 'positions':      pos      desc status
 0  12454  director      a
 1  65444   manager      i}
```

I want to use a list of existing data frames rather than csv files. I tried using a list without quotes but I get an error:

```
l = [employees, positions]
d = {}
for x in l:
    d[x] = x
```

...but I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Comment: what doesn't work about it?

Comment: If `df1` and `df2` are variables in the global namespace, you can access them by using `globals()['df1']`, etc.  Although better practice would be to store them in the dictionary when you load them in.

Comment: `l = ['df1','df2']` is a list of strings. you need a list of dataframes.

Comment: I think a solution like `d[x] = eval(x)` would work, but I'm not too familiar with `eval`.

Comment: if I use a list of data frames such as l = [df1, df2] then I get an error "Dataframe objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're defining a list of strings and building a dictionary mapping each string to itself. Much simpler is to use `enumerate` with an iterable of dataframes. Assuming `df1` and `df2` are dataframes:

```
d = dict(enumerate((df1, df2), 1))
```

Then access your dataframes via `d[1]` and `d[2]`. If you *really* want your keys to be strings `"df1"` and `"df2"`, you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {'df'+str(i): j for i, j in enumerate((df1, df2), 1)}
```

A better naming convention, in my opinion, is to use your filenames as keys:

```
files = ['employees', 'positions']
d = {f: pd.read_csv(f'P:\\python_work\\data_sets\\{f}.csv') for f in files}
```

Comment: I want to use the option similar to where you use filenames as keys, but I want to use the data frame names as keys (i.e. employees and positions are existing data frames rather than csv files).

Comment: @Dread, So the example in your question isn't really accurate? Here are the things you should **not** do: use `eval`, use `globals`, use `locals`. What you *can* do is read dataframes straight into your dictionary, e.g. `d = {}; d['employees'] = pd.read_csv(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, I added `k` to show how you should use enumerate in this case

```
l = ['employees','positions']
k = [1,2]
d = {}
for index,x in enumerate(l):
    d[x] = k[index]
```

Returns for d:

```
{'employees': 1, 'positions': 2}
```

Than excess you dataframe by:

```
df_1 = d.get('employees')
```

(ofcourse you have to replace k[index] with the creation of your dataframe)

Answer (score -1):

There is already a dictionary with all the declared variables in memory available via the `locals()` or the `globals()` builtin functions, depending whether the dataframes are defined as local or global variables. You should be able to access your DataFrame as such:

```
locals()['df1']
```

Comment: In my opinion, using `globals()` for this purpose is not recommended, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables